# Meaning of minMaxLoc returned values

Tags: c++, opencv

I've got an image of 320x240 B/W pixels from wich I extract a ROI of 80x60. 
On the ROI I compute a reduce `reduce(ROI, hist, 1, CV_REDUCE_SUM, CV_32FC1);` and then I evaluate the parameters of the histogram by using `minMaxLoc(hist, &minVal, &maxVal, 0, 0);`. Everything works fine: the results are correct but I've got a question.

Why the minVal and maxVal assumes some very high values? I've got that
maxVal=10710
minVal=5100
and calculating the average on the hist with:

```
for (int i=0; i<cols-1; i++) {
   float nextValue = hist.at<float>(i+1,0);
   avg+=nextValue;
}
avg=avg/cols;
```

I see that the averege value is
avg=8440

Should all those values be smaller due to the ROI?

Thank you

Comment: Assuming you have an 8-bit greyscale input, with a width of 80 pixels, the `reduce` could produce entries up to 80*255 = 20400.

Comment: I think you're right!